# HttpURLConnection multiple requests

Tags: java, html, rest, request, connection

I am new at REST api and I am trying simple code.

```
URL url = new URL("https://A.B/C");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
}
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
conn.disconnect();
```

problem is, that I am trying to make multiple requests with same connection and I am struggling. Only possible solution I've "found" is to open new connection and create new buffered reader. I found that very inefficient. Is there any way, please, how can I recycle my opened connection and just update values over time?

Comment: search the literature for "connection keep alive".

Comment: I won't find satisfying answer. Do I need to call .openStream every time?

Comment: No, you should not need to.  But unless "connection keep alive" has been specified within the HTTP request, the other party (the server) will close the connection from their end immediately after returning their response, in which case further attempts to use the connection on your end will fail.  So, you need to both keep the connection open, ***and*** specify "connection keep alive" in the request.

Comment: Aha, now I have idea what you ment! thanks! I was searching for something else. And do you know how do I specify alive http request?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not remember right now, and I do not seem to have any source code that does that.  Otherwise, I would have answered the question instead of commenting.